# Check for duplicate rows while transferring data from text file to excel

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis, ssis-2012, dts

Platform : SSIS

I am new to SSIS and trying to check for duplicate rows while transferring the data from text file to excel file. Heard about cache transform can be used but I am not really sure about it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to handle this is use an Aggregate transform between the source and destination. In it, group by all the columns in the source to eliminate duplicates. I have used this technique, and it works well.

This could be slow if the source is large.

Comment: I also want to check if the record already exists in the excel file.

Comment: You can use a lookup task for that. The lookup task has 2 outputs, one for records found in the destination, the other for records not found in the destination. If you only want to add records that don't exist, then just send the "not found" output to the spreadsheet.

Comment: But lookup can only be used when source is database and not flat file connection right?

Comment: That is an unfortunate limitation. I assumed that you could do it with a Jet driver, or something long those line. Perhaps not. You might think about using a script task to compare the source and destination before writing records. I don't have a good example of that handy.

Comment: Alright. Please let me know if there are any possibilities . An example would be helpful

Comment: http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/ssis-how-to-use-flat-file-or-excel-file.html. I have not tested this, but this could get you going in the right direction. It seems, this is where the cache transform comes into play.